# Checking that the user entered an integer

Tags: java

I am writing a command line program and would like to make the the user to enters a valid age (integer). By using the Scanner class, I have something like this:

```
int getAge() {
   Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   int age;
   boolean isValid = false;

   while(!isValid) {
      System.out.println("Please enter your age");
      if (myScanner.hasNext()) {
        if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
           age = myScanner.nextInt();
           isValid = true;
        } else {
           System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        }
      }
   }

   return age;
}
```

The problem being that while in the loop it keeps reading input without waiting for a new value. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading any token in your `else` path thus processing the same input over and over again. Just add the following line

```
myScanner.next();
```

inside the `else`-block.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use something like this.  To read an entire line using a `BufferedReader` then parse the integer from the string and catch any exception that might occur.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String s = br.readLine();
int intVal;
try {
  intVal = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  //Do Something
}
```

You could place this inside your loop.  (Yes I realize it doesn't use Scanner... just wanted to show an alternate approach.)